# How can i append twig templates inside a loop?

Tags: drupal, twig

Here i am iterating through a loop and rendering different twig templates inside a div with id {{ divId }} on the action of click. But when i am doing this, the html is rendering separately instead of rendering inside the div. Here i am attaching the code and image to further explain the issue.

```
<script id="template_{{ field_id }}" type="text/html">
            
                {% set scriptSeperatorId = 'separator_' ~ field_id ~ "-" ~ '{section_id}' %}
                <span class="sepRater" id="{{ scriptSeperatorId }}"></span>
                {% set divId = field_id ~ '-{section_id}' %}
                <div id="{{ divId }}">
                    {% for multi_input_template_field_key, multi_input_template_field_details in multi_input_template_fields %}
                        {% set multi_input_template_field_id = field_id ~ '-' ~ '{section_id}' ~ '-' ~ multi_input_template_field_key %}
                        {% set multi_input_template_field_name = field_name ~ ':' ~ '{section_id}' ~ ':' ~ multi_input_template_field_key %}
                        {% set multi_input_template_field_value = '' %}

                        {% if multi_input_template_field_details[default] is defined %}
                            {% set multi_input_template_field_value = multi_input_template_field_details.default %}
                        {% endif %}

                        {% set view_data = {} %}
                        {% set view_data = view_data|merge({'field_id': (multi_input_template_field_id)}) %}
                        {% set view_data = view_data|merge({'field_name': (multi_input_template_field_name)}) %}
                        {% set view_data = view_data|merge({'field_value': (multi_input_template_field_value)}) %}
                        {% set view_data = view_data|merge({'field_details': (multi_input_template_field_details)}) %}

                        {% set data = {} %}
                        {% set data = data|merge({'view_data': (view_data)}) %}
                        {% set data = data|merge({'field_details': (multi_input_template_field_details)}) %}
                        {% set data = data|merge({'categories': (categories)}) %}

                        
                        {% include "field-type-render.html.twig" with data %}
                    {% endfor %}
                   
                    <div class="form-box">
                        <label class="pure-material-textfield-outlined smBtnArea">
                            <button type="button" class=" btn btn-info btn-ad  removeBtn"  id="remove_multiinput_section_{{ field_id }}-{section_id}">Remove</button>
                            <span style="color:red;display:none;" class="spancantremove{{ field_id }}-{section_id}">You can't remove the last element </span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </script>
```

The type of output i am supposed to get is:

[image: Here the both the inputs are inside the div]

The output i am getting:

[image: Here both the inputs are outside div]

Comment: Your image doesn't make much sense. Can you post the actually generated HTML (and not the formatted sourcecode of any developer tools)

Comment: The include tag is not working with the inner for loop instead the include tag renders the template separately

Comment: 100% sure it doesn't - [demo](https://twigfiddle.com/gnzn4e). We can't help you without any more information/details. Most likely you have some invalid/broken HTML causing the browser to render the output other than you expect.

Comment: can you suggest me a way in which on button click the twig template can be appended

Comment: Let me get this clear, your problem happens when clicking a button? Please update your question with the generated HTML and javascript you are using. This has nothing to do with twig nor drupal if it involves clientside actions

Comment: the problem is instead of appending twig template on the click it automatically includes the template, but whenever i click on the add more button, it no more includes the twig template